# pysftp can't create log file - permission denied

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, paramiko

I have a small service written in Python 3 which uses pysftp:

```
with pysftp.Connection(
    host=host,
    username=connection_data["user"],
    port=connection_data["port"], log=log_file, cnopts=cnopts
) as srv:
```

…

and when I run it (`python3 pythonprog.py`) I get the following error:

> > PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mydisk/folder/logs/pysftp-20181127-231208.log'

Obviously, I don't get this error if I run it with `sudo python3 pythonprog.py`.

I checked the permissions for this folder:

> ls -l
>
> > drwxrwxrwx+ 2 myuser myuser 4096 Nov 27 22:38 logs

I also changed ACL with `setfacl`. Basically, whatever I do the error is still there. How can I grant this permission?

Answer (score 0):

The service is running as someone -- that someone needs permission to write to that file or folder.  This is not a code problem, its a permission problem.  sudo is not the solution to running the code.  I'm taking it that it is running as you?  Can you write to that file/folder?

Comment: Yes, it's running as 'myuser' and user has full permissions on that folder. I checked by 'nano test.txt' and I created that file without any problem (under 'myuser').